# Is a linear map (transformation) always a matrix multiplication even when it is not from $:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^k$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Definition: Let $A$ be an $m\times n$ matrix with entries from a field $F.$ We denote by $L_A$ the mapping $L_A:F^n\to F^m$ defined by $L_A(x)=Ax$ (the matrix product of $A$ and $x$) for each column vector $x\in F^n.$

Now, V and W are vector spaces; T: V → W denotes a linear transformations; A denotes a matrix.

> Question: True or false: $T = L_A$ for some matrix $A$?

The text says: "False. If T is a map of the form $F^n → F^m$ then Theorem 2.15 shows that $T = L_A$ for some matrix A. Otherwise, it is unclear what $L_A$ means (for example, what does
$L_A : P_2(ℝ) → P_2(ℝ)$ mean?)"

I don't really get the answer since $P_2(ℝ)$ has a basis of (1, x, x^2) so why doesn't $L_A : P_2(ℝ) → P_2(ℝ)$ have a matrix representation?

I have reviewed the answer at this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2547357/is-a-linear-map-transformation-always-a-matrix-multiplication) but my question here is slightly different. $P_2(ℝ)$ is a set of polynomials with degree up to 2 and coefficients in ℝ.

Edit: The text gives this definition of $L_A$
"Let A be an $m \times n$ matrix with entries from a field F. We denote by $_$ the mapping $_:^ → ^$ defined by $_()=$ (the matrix product of A and x) for each column vector $x € ^$. We call $_$ a left-multiplication transformation."

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141783/discussion-on-question-by-khanh-is-a-linear-map-transformation-always-a-matrix).